# PHP - Create multiple XML files from Mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm pulling data from my mysql database and using it to create an XML file. the idea is for each row of data pulled, it be appended to its own XML file

Here's my sample code:

```
//sql statement here
$results = $fetch_data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $data)
{
    $invoice_no = $data["invoice_no"];

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $Order = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('Order'));
    $OrderHead = $Order->appendChild($doc->createElement('OrderHead'));

    $Schema = $doc->createElement('Schema');
    $Schema->appendChild($doc->createElement('Version', '3.05'));
    $OrderHead->appendChild($Schema);

    $CrossReference = $doc->createElement('CrossReference', $invoice_no);
    $OrderHead->appendChild($CrossReference);

    //more xml code...

    $doc->save($invoice_no.".xml", LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}
```

As shown above, i'm looping through the data from the database to create the XML file then want to save each file(s)  prefixed by the `$invoice_no`. But only one XML file is created and to be more specific, only the last record pulled from the database is used to create the XML file. this is happening though i'm creating the file inside my loop

where could i be going wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that $invoice_no is the same for different iterations of the loop? In that case the file would be overwritten. Try adding some debug statements.

Comment: you're right. my invoice_no's are the same. don't know how i missed it. thanks!